# jquery new line programmatically inside contenteditable

Tags: jquery, keypress, contenteditable

i'm trying to simulate the ENTER button programmatically in javascript/jquery inside a contenteditable, i've tried all the solutions you can find on stackoverflow but with no success, so i created a pen to see wether was my code to mess it or not, and seems like it just doesn't work on its own.

here is the demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WgwEXE

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = e.keyCode = 13;
$('#boxid').focus();
$('#boxid').trigger(e);
});
```

```css
#boxid {
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxid" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button id="btn">new line</button>
```

Comment: Why not just append a linebreak?

Comment: I can't because in my original code i have an essential event listener on keypress == 13.

Comment: Call the function after appending?

Answer (score 0):

Use this answer,I think it will fix your problem

$('#btn').on('click', function(){

var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");

e.which = e.keyCode = 13;

$('#boxid').focus();

$('#boxid').trigger(e);
});

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do?.I think you are try to enter button inside div then event trigger. Am i right?

Comment: I'll rephrase it in 4 different ways:   simulate the user press of the ENTER/ESCAPE key (code 13), fake the press of the human triggered button ENTER programmatically, doing programmatically what a user would do pressing the enter key, programmatically press the enter key as if user pressed it on the keyboard.